# How to view data from specific column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Hi I'm super new to postgresql and I am trying to view data from just one column of my table. However, all the things I've found online so far are about viewing all the content available in the table. Is there any way to view the entries of just one column?

Comment: Select column from table where condition; unless I am missing something?

Comment: Did you mean *"Is there any way to view just one column of the entries?"*

Comment: If you want to see only one column, select only one column: `select some_column from the_table where ....`